# One Promise Executed at time in an Rx.Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I want the `console.log` to print 0 to 9, and only a single promise lazy evaluated at each step.

```
Rx.Observable.range(0,10)
   .map((i)=>new Promise((res,rej)=>setTimeout(()=>res(i),Math.random()*100)))
   .subscribe(console.log,console.error)
```

This code causes the promise to be logged and all the promises start at the same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concatMap` operator instead of `map`, it allows you to project the source observable one by one serially

```
Rx.Observable.range(0,10)
    .concatMap((i)=>new Promise((res,rej)=>setTimeout(()=>res(i),Math.random()*100)))
    .subscribe(console.log,console.error)
```

Comment: Any ideas how to get the promise to not kick off before it finishes?  In this example they all fire then the subscribe hits in order they were created.  I'm trying to limit the number created.

Comment: The on success callback to `subscribe` is only called when the source observable emits a value which in this case is when the promise resolves, so if your promise never resolves, the on success callback to `subscribe` will never be called, subscribing to the observable won't make your promise resolve right away, it's because your short random time `setTimeout` that makes it appear the promises resolve right away, you can use `delay` operator to add delay to the emission, and use `filter` operator before the `concatMap` to filter out values you don't want before creating the promises

Comment: There is no way to prevent creating a promise after the `concatMap` obviously